# Sed Appending Right After Match

Tags: linux, sed

Appending string right after the ['trusted_domains' => string].

```
sed 's/'trusted_domains' =>//g' file.txt
```

Does the search but how to append right after the match??

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts, please do mention your samples of input and expected output in your question for making it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 i want the output to  be : 'trusted_domains' => '192.168.xx.xx/24'.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, with sed it will replace match with replace value.

```
sed -r "s/'trusted_domains' =>/'trusted_domains' => www.google.com/g"
```

***Sample on a command line:***

```
echo "some random text ['trusted_domains' =>] again some random text after" | sed -r "s/'trusted_domains' =>/'trusted_domains' => www.google.com/g"
```

**Output:**

> some random text ['trusted_domains' => www.google.com] again some
> random text after

---

***Sample on a file:*** *(Input file : test_file.txt)*

```
some random text ['trusted_domains' =>] again some random text after
```

**command :**

```
sed "s/'trusted_domains' =>/'trusted_domains' => www.google.com/g" test_file.txt
```

**Output:**

> some random text ['trusted_domains' => www.google.com] again some
> random text after